# Moving multiple items from one list to another in single line in Python

Tags: python, list, move

I'd like to move multiple items from one list to another.
The items are to be removed from the first list and inserted at the end of the second list.
The value of the items are unknown but the indexes of the items are known.
I'd like to do so in one line of code.
The code below does what I'd like but not in one line of code:

```
listOne = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listTwo = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

listTwo = listTwo +listOne[0:2]
listOne = listOne[2:]
```

Is there a clean way to do so using functions (such as pop(), inser() etc.) in conjunction with each other?

Comment: listOne, listTwo = listOne[2:], listTwo.extend(listOne[0:2]) 

isnt it good enough :)?

Comment: "Indexes of the items are known..."  - how are they specified? As a tuple? A string?

Comment: The above returns a none value for listTwo.

Comment: List extend doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like that

```py
listOne = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listTwo = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Must respect this criteria : 0 <= X < Y <= len(listOne)
Y = 2
X = 0

listTwo.extend([listOne.pop(X) for _ in range(Y-X)])
print(listTwo) # [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1]
print(listOne) # [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Correction based on the [jarmod comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72376679/moving-multiple-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-single-line-in-python/72376760#comment127861116_72376760)

Comment: Could fail if the starting index of the sublist to move is not 0. Would need to modify the pop call to pop(X) for sublist [X:Y].

Comment: Something like: `listTwo.extend([listOne.pop(X) for _ in range(Y-X)])` for sublist [X:Y] assuming Y>X.

Comment: How is the hyphen in range(Y-X) interpreted? Just another way for writing range(X, Y)?

Comment: It will just do the subtraction, it is the same as `range(0, S)` where `S = Y - X`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your solution itself on one line -

```py
listOne = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listTwo = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
listTwo, listOne = listTwo +listOne[0:2], listOne[2:]

print(listTwo)
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1]
print(listOne)
# [2, 3, 4, 5]
```